Next.js Internationalization App and Pages Router Issue
We have next.js project and we have both pages and app router. We are using next-translate and next-translate plugin for translation and we have i18n.js file setup correctly. The problem is I keep getting 404 when I change the language from english to Spanish so our Default url is www.student.com/:countryName/id
When someone hits Spanish, it changes to www.student.com/sp/:countryName/id
But now with app router it keeps throwing 404. I have tried writing rewrites and tried middleware as well but the pathname does not have sp in there. It is always :countryName/id so it cannot match any route and it throws 404
I have tried adding app->[lang]->[country]->[id]. This also does not work and throws 404 for urls without language as well.
On the pages router it works fine but it is not working for App Router.
Our i18n.js has pages section which has /[country]/[id]. What else we can try?
